# CakePHP migrate records with different indecies

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two similar CakePHP Projects with records of two models (Applications and Screens). Structure can be found here below:

**Applications**

[image]

**Screens**

[image]

Basically I want to migrate some records of these models from one Project to the other. My issue now is that the IDs of these migrated records are already occupied in the destination database.

I am sure there has to be an built-in featue of the CakePHP framework that offers the migration of records, but i cant seem to figure it out.

Someone already thumbled over this before?

Comment: There is no such built-in feature, you'll have handle that yourself.

Comment: have been afraid of this .. :/ but i already imagined since there is no unique identifier other than the ID itself. Thanks anyways!